# Как закрыть полностью приложение, если при запуске оно скрыто? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Такая проблема: мне надо чтобы приложение на фоне выполнило свой функционал и закрылось. Для этого для окна MainWindow (наследуется от Window) я установил Visibily = Hidden. Ну и написал как обычно Close(). Но дело в том что, приложение не закрывается, оно висит как работающие. Я по пробовал Application.Current.Shotdown(), но он все равно так же висит и работает. Есть ли способ, как закрыть приложение в таком состояние(скрыт)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820357/how-do-i-exit-a-wpf-application-programmatically

Comment: `Close()` должен закрывать любое окно. Если не работает, значит проблема в другом месте, либо окно не одно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте эту команду `Application.Exit()`

Comment: Я нашел способ (он близок к вашему). Дело в том что у меня проблема теперь новая. A valid active Window is needed to update the Taskbar. Я не очень понимаю как ее решить

Comment: @kanejons2 в комментарии под вопросом - есть ссылка на подобный же вопрос на enSO, и там в комметариях под ответом есть ответ и на этот ваш вопрос в том числе :)

Comment: у вас в программе 2 окно? 1-видимый 2-скрытый в фоне работает?

Comment: @UmarEgamberdiev нет у меня одно окно. И это одно окно скрыто

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков к сожалению там не было ответа на мою проблему. Дело в том что программа не может открыть всплывающие окно на панели задач. Поэтому и выходит такая ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Для решения свое проблемы я использовал `Application.Current.Shotdown()`
Косяк с

> A valid active Window is needed to update the Taskbar

Был вызван с тем что мне нужен был JumpList. И именно на это он ругался. Для решения я добавил в App.xaml разметку с аналогичным названием, но не заполнил его. А заполнение оставил прошлое с кода на c#. Это помогло и программа работает теперь хорошо. Хотел бы спасибо сказать @Umar Egamberdiev
и @Владимир Клыков. Именно от них я понял в какую сторону мне двигаться.